# How to combine multiple files with similar names in different folders by using unix command?

Tags: io-redirection, cat

I know this question has been asked and answered before, I have tried the code but I do not get a correct output.

I have 2 folders: vanila1 and vanila2, each has 400 files with similar names

```
ls vanila1
MB.2613.007_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_all
MB.2613.007_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_all
MB.2613.007_14.ED14_IA2A35-2_310_all

ls vanila2
MB.2613.007_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_all
MB.2613.007_0022.ED9_SD2A27-1_180_all
MB.2613.007_14.ED14_IA2A35-2_310_all
```

I want to combine files with identical names and I am using this:

```
ls vanila1 | while read FILE; do
  cat vanila1/"$FILE" vanila2/"$FILE" >> all_combined/"$FILE"
done
```

I do not get a correct output, the number of lines in combined file is more that the sum of file1 and file 2. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Theophrastus, yes. seems your possible clue did the job for me, thanks for that.

Comment: It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs") to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: I do prefer [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in BashGuide.

Comment: You might observe that I do in fact link to that exact article.

Comment: I got the same result with either `>` or `>>`. The only difference between the two is that `>` overwrites the contents of the file if it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hunch that you may have run your loop more than once, and since you use the `>>` redirection operator, which *appends* data, your result files grows every time.

Instead (and here I'm avoiding using `ls` too, see the discussion in "[Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)" for reasons):

```
for name in vanila1/*; do
    base_name=${name##*/}

    if [ -f "vanila2/$base_name" ]; then
        cat "$name" "vanila2/$base_name" >"all_combined/$base_name"
    else
        printf 'No file in vanila2 corresponds to "%s"\n' "$name" >&2
    fi
done
```

The variable substitution `${name##*/}` transforms a pathname like `vanila1/MB.2613.007_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_all` into just `MB.2613.007_0021.ED4_KS1A29-7_338_all`, i.e. it removes all things before the `/`, including the slash (this is the filename component of the pathname, or "the basename").  This may be replaced by `$(basename "$name")`.

If there is a file in `vanila2` corresponding to the name picked up from `vanila1`, the two are concatenated and put into the `all_combined` directory.  If not, there is a diagnostic message about this fact.

By using `>` rather than `>>`, any existing file in `all_combined` with the same name will be replaced rather than appended to.

---

If you have *other files* or directories in `vanila1`, then you may want to modify the pattern `vanila1/*` in the loop to something that matches only the files that you are interested in, for example `vanila1/*_all` or similar.

Comment: thanks so much for the code and very helpful explanations on it. There is one little question in your code that I could not understand as I am learning programming: if [ -f "vanila2/$base_name" ], what does this part do? I mean -f?

Comment: @Anna1364 The test `[ -f "filename" ]` will be true if there exists a file whose name is `filename`.  In the code I using a similar test to check whether `vanila2/$base_name` corresponds to an existing file. The `-f` test chocks specifically for an existing _regular file_, while other tests like `-d` checks whether the given name is that of an existing _directory_.  See `man test`.

Answer (score -1):

So you have files with identical names in two directories, and where both files are present you with to concatenate them?

```
for file in dir1/*; do
   otherfile="$(basename "$file")"
   if [[ -r dir2/"${otherfile}" ]]; then
       cat "$file" dir2/"$otherfile" >> combined/"$otherfile"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the questioner's main point, which was to figure out why his/her result is seemingly longer than the sum of its parts.